# How to place an image on top of another one

Tags: html, css

Inside a div, there is a picture that should have 10px margin in all directions from the DIV's border. On the left bottom corner of the picture there is an about-image.
The picture is only displayed when its loaded in the DOM through jquery.
The problem is that the existence of the about-image dislocates the picture downwards as many pixels as the height of the about-image.

I am looking for the cleanest possible alternative to keep the picture inside the DIV and still display the about-image on top of it. Setting the picture as background will not work since i need the picture to load at once.

Any improvement on the #about css would be greatly appreciated.
Below is a full html page that reproduces the issue

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Troubleshooting :: align the main picture inside the DIV</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body  {
   background-color: #000000;
}

#about {
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
    top:82%;
    left:3%;
}

#pic {
    width:100%;
    height:96%;
}

#main-content-image {
    height:100%;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#main-content {
    height:490px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #777777; 
}
#main-content-image.loading {
  background: url(http://farros.gr/images/ajax-loader2.gif) no-repeat center center;
}

a  {
   text-decoration: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #868686;
   outline:none;
}

.hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function(){    

        $(function () {
            var img = new Image();
            $(img).load(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).width('100%');
                $(this).height('96%');
                $('#main-content-image').removeClass('loading').append(this);
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }).error(function () {
                // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
            }).attr('src', 'http://farros.gr/images/bg.jpg');
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div id="main-content-image" class="loading">
            <a href="#"><img id="about" src='http://farros.gr/images/about.png' alt='Haris Farros'/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use position: absolute for the about pic and you can put it anywhere you want. Also make sure to set #main-content-image to position: relative so it becomes the reference point for the about image.

edit: I've tested it with your html, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

A (dirty) javascript solution would be to give the anchor that wraps your image the "about" id instead, and set #about to 'display: block;'

Then, inside your image load callback, add the following statement:

```
$(this).css({marginTop: "-40px"});
```

Beware downvoters; I'm not a fan of having markup rely on javascript code execution, but that's what happens in his code already anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning will accomplish what you seek:

```
#main-content-image {
  position: relative; /* Needed so absolute positioning works on child */
}

#about { 
  position: absolute; /* absolutely positioning it takes it out of the document flow */
  bottom: 10px; /* You said you wanted it on the bottom left, right? */
  left: 10px; 
}
```